# How to perform multiple logistic regression for a continuous dependent variable with values between 0 and 1?

Tags: regression

I thought that logistic regression should only be used for true binary variables (`0` or `1`), but now one reviewer of my paper is asking me to perform multiple logistic regression for a dependent variable that is relative abundance (i.e. proportion data). I saw that logistic regression can also be used when there is an upper boundary to the value of the dependent variable. However, when I try to perform logistic regression in R with my data, I have the following error message:

> In eval(family$initialize): non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!

My dependent variable is the number of species weighted by abundance or cumulative abundance of all species, that belong to a cluster (group) in a certain plot, divided by the total abundance in a plot (considering all functional groups), so it varies between `0` and `1`. I have seen that some methods to apply logistic regression require two columns as the dependent variable, one with the resulting abundance and the other with 100-abundance (can also be 1-abundance), but I could not apply it given my limited R knowledge.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  If you could post your code that is returning the error we can help you better.

Comment: put some code here